# How to compare characters in two different strings

Tags: java, string

Lets say i have "jfk" and "jfc". I want to iterate through both strings and find out if and where they differ. I am trying to see if the strings are anagrams. "new door" and "one word" are anagrams. If its not an anagram i want the code to tell me by how many characters the strings differ. The jfk and jfc differ by 1. "macd" and "mebc" differ by 2 and they cant be anagrams. If the two strings are different lengths then they can't be anagrams.

I tried iterating through the strings but that's when i got stuck. I have no idea how to iterate through both strings at the same time and find out how if they differ by certain characters or not. I only got as far as checking if both strings were the same length.

````
 static void isAnagram(List <String> s1, List <String> s2) {  
        if (s1.length() != s2.length()) {  
            System.out.println("Not anagrams");  
        } else {  
            for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
               for(int j = 0; j < s2.lenth(); j++) {//i know that iterating through both strings like this does not make sense but i am stuck.
        }```
````

Answer (score 1):

Convert the arrays to char arrays. Then sort the arrays alphabetically after that compare them character by character.

Answer (score 0):

`String str = "abc";
char[] chars = str.toCharArray();`
you can use this to convert string to char array,next it will be very easy loop the char array by running a simple if condition and increment a variable which will tell the difference of words.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed additional libraries, you should have a look at Google’s Guava, espacially at `com.google.common.collect.Multiset<E>` and it’s implementations. You can put the characters of each string into an `Multiset<Character>` (not a Multiset, that will not work, as E must be a reference type, no primitive). Both strings are anagrams if `multiset1.equals(multiset2)`.

Of both for loops, it seems to me that you only need one of the loop and use the same counter for both strings?